# How do I unbox an object from RadListViewItemEventArgs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, telerik

I have a RadListView that is loaded with a list of objects called "FullTicket" or in otherwords ListView.DataSource = List. On the ItemDataBound event, I am trying to do some things with each item, but unfortunately I can't seem to unbox the object.

So I have (object sender, RadListViewItemEventArgs e), and I'm trying to get the actually object, so I tried this

```
var itemObj = (FullTicket)e.Item;
```

But it is saying "Cannot convert type from RadListViewItem to FullTicket". I went looking around inside of e.Item.* to see if there were any other attributes that might actually hold the object, but nothing is shining in there. Does anyone know how to get my object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var listViewDataItem = e.Item as RadListViewDataItem;
if (listViewDataItem != null)
{
    var itemObj = listViewDataItem.DataItem;
    // ...
}
```

`RadListViewDataItem` derives from `RadListViewItem` and adds the `DataItem` property, which holds your object.